LaunchedEffect unexpected behavior not getting composable animation properly
I have a flow in my screen's composable, continuously receiving from backend new values, which I transform to screen offsets for animation purposes and put in a map called markersMap:
@Composable
fun Screen() {

    val receivedFlow = viewModel.receiverFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(
        initialValue = null,
        minActiveState = Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
    )

    receivedFlow.value?.let { received ->
        markersMap[received.stationId]?.offset =  markersMap[received.stationId]?.nextOffset
        markersMap[received.stationId]?.nextOffset = Offset(received.x, received.y)
    }
}

Then I have a composable looping each second over all items in markersMap, in order to create an animation from their previous offset to their next offset
@Composable
fun NativeMarkersAnimator() {
    val offsetsMap = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf<Long, Animatable<Offset,AnimationVector2D>>()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            markersMap.forEach { marker ->
                val targetOffset = marker.value.nextOffset
                targetOffset?.let { target ->
                    offsetsMap[marker.value.stationId] =
                        Animatable(marker.value.offset, Offset.VectorConverter)
                    offsetsMap[marker.value.stationId]?.animateTo(target, tween(900))
                }
            }
            delay(1000)
        }
    }
    //CANVAS
}

and obviously, also withinNativeMarkersAnimator, the Canvas that will recompose for rendering animations:
@Composable
fun NativeMarkersAnimator() {
    val offsetsMap = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf<Long, Animatable<Offset,AnimationVector2D>>()
    }

    // LAUNCHED EFFECT in code snippet above


    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        offsetsMap.forEach { offset ->
            val image = markersMap[offset.key]?.bitmap?.asImageBitmap()
            image?.let {
                drawImage(
                    image = image,
                    topLeft = offset.value.value
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

My issue: the values of markersMap found in LaunchedEffect are not consistent with the values received from the flow: if I get from the flow e.g. Offset(400,300), I put it into markersMap at the key x, I get an entry <x, Offset(400,300)>.
But during the Launched Effect loop I find a totally different value from the same entry, not <x,Offset(400,300)> but lets say <x, Offset(600,600)>, the value looks random or very old and it remains the same a lot, let's say I update 20 times the entry from the flow, but from the LaunchedEffect it's still the same (wrong) value. This means the offset anim will start from the same point a lot of times!
So the results is that animations kinda loop, starting from the same initial offset point and doing the same path again and again.
I think the issue is complex and that's the reason chatgpt can't help so much. Any hint would be of huge worth. Thanks in advance
EDIT
As in comments below, this specifically fixes the issue (putting all animation logic inside receiver flow):
receivedFlow.value?.let { received ->
    coroutineScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {

            handleDenmAlertData(received.denmAlertData, viewModel)

            nativeAnimationManager?.let { nativeAnimationManager ->
                val map = nativeAnimationManager.mapboxMap
                val point = Point.fromLngLat(received.lastLongitude, received.lastLatitude)
                val projected = map.pixelForCoordinate(point)

                if (!markersMap.containsKey(received.stationId)) {

                    markersMap[received.stationId] = RoadUserMarker(
                        stationId = received.stationId,
                        prevOffset = Offset(
                            x = projected.x.toFloat(),
                            y = projected.y.toFloat()
                        ),
                        point = point,
                        stationType = received.stationType,
                        bitmap = findBitmap(received),
                        nextOffset = null,
                        animatedOffset = null,
                        lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    )
                }
                else {
                    markersMap[received.stationId]?.let {marker ->

                        marker.nextOffset?.let {
                            marker.prevOffset = it
                            println("Current offset***: " + markersMap[received.stationId]?.prevOffset)
                        }
                        marker.nextOffset = Offset(projected.x.toFloat(), projected.y.toFloat())
                        marker.animatedOffset = Animatable(marker.prevOffset, Offset.VectorConverter)
                        marker.animatedOffset!!.animateTo(marker.nextOffset!!, tween(900))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        markersMap.forEach { markerEntry ->
            val image = markerEntry.value.bitmap.asImageBitmap()
            markerEntry.value.animatedOffset?.let {
                drawImage(
                    image = image,
                    topLeft = it.value
                )
            }
        }
    }


Where do you collect receivedFlow? Also, accessing the value property looks to me a little bit like a MutableStateFlow which would not be suited to retrieve a history of changed values, it can only be used to retrieve the current value - all intermittent values will be dropped. Please [edit] your question to also add the view model code pertaining to the flow.

Hi, I've edited my question. Flow is collected from viewmodel flow and is defined in composable.

Anyway I don't think Flow collection is the issue as the received values are correctly written in the markersMap (the intermittent drop shouldn't be a problem too), but in the animation composable, the markersMap is read inconsistently with respect to what was written on by the flow.

You're right, the flow collection looks fine. The way you handle new flow values, on the other hand, is not how Compose is designed to be used. Compose is a declarative framework. Instead off creating some a history of previous states you should only define what should happen according to the current state. I'm not sure what exactly causes your problem but I'm pretty confident that it goes away when you refactor your code so that your view model's flow will provide the history of previous values instead of the UI needing to take care of it.

Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit more on your solution? I'm not sure how I'm currently taking care of previous values in the UI, how should I change the flows to get histories and how collected values from the flow can be stored as mutable states to force recompositions?

The view model should provide all values that the UI needs at any given time. If the UI needs past values then the view model should also provide these together with the new values. Just think of it as a static state: Whenever the UI takes a look at the view model it should provide a complete set of data, everything that is needed for the UI right now. As it currently is your UI needs to keep its own history of previous values by adding new flow values to markersMap. So what the view model provides at any given time is incomplete: ...

... The UI apparently also needs what the view model's flow emitted in the past. If the UI needs previous values then the view model should store that somewhere, not the UI itself. Your composables should stay largely stateless. That's a bigger refactoring that will, as I previously stated, probably prevent the current problem from even occuring, but it doesn't address the problem itself. It is therefore out of scope for the current question (and its comments) since that focuses only on the Compose part of your UI while the refactoring will primarily target your view model.

Thank you for the input, really appreciated. I'll try this refactoring. Right now I've fixed the issue, by simply deleting "state" variables and managing the animations directly inside the flows just using the last received values, not holding a state anymore. But to start an animation every 1/10 second (the interval for a new flow value to arrive from backend) is not scalable so I'll try to make them start every 1 second, so I'll try out your solution.

After your refactoring you can post your code at the sister site [codereview.se] to get some more input, if you want. They have a different focus there and questions are expected to provide code that already works as intended. Also see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.
